# Java read from file two different type of objects

Tags: java

In my file I have saved my hashmap in the header which I can succesfully read, but when I try to read the following bytes, I get an error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: C9
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(Unknown Source)
```

Here's my code:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    try {
        map = (HashMap<Integer, String>) ois.readObject();

        byte b = ois.readByte();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How I write:

```
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileOutPath);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

        oos.writeObject(codePathMap);

        BitSet buffer = new BitSet();

        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < codePathMap.get(i).length(); i++) {
                if (codePathMap.get(b).charAt(i) == '1') {
                    buffer.set(bitIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        os.write(buffer.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Please consider [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58444549/edit) the contents of the file to your question.

Comment: It's a compressed file in bytes

Comment: Well, the code where you write the objects would be good to see. Btw HashMap guarantees no specific order when you iterate over it.

Comment: The code where you write the file is *essential* to see. And if it's a 'compressed file in bytes' where is the code to decompress it? And, contrary to suggestions above, the actual file content is of no interest, at least unless you provide it in hex.

Comment: I added how I write to file

Comment: So you wrote a hashmap to `oos` and then a byte array to `os`, without flushing `oos` first, which is pretty optimistic, and then you're reading a hashmap and then a single byte, both from `ois`, which isn't going to work. And are you closing `oos` or `os`? You need to read and write the same things, and use the object streams for everything when doing so, and close the object streams only, not the underlying streams. And there is no compression here.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mismatch between writes and reads algorithms.
Short story, you're using `FileOutputStream` in order to **write** your `byte[]`, but `ObjectInputStream` in order to **read** it. Those classes uses different ways of how they treat the stored data.

Hence, you **SHOULD** always use `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream`.

So, just to fix your error, instead of using `FileOutputStream`:

```
os.write(buffer.toByteArray());
```

you might use `ObjectOutputStream (oos)` in order to write the `byte[]` as:

```
oos.write(buffer.toByteArray());
```

Side note: `invalid type code: C9`, C9 is actual value of the written `byte[]`, so `C9` is `201`, which `ObjectInputStream` interprets as Java type (that's how `ObjectOutputStream` serializes the data.

Comment: He should really use `writeObject()` on the byte array, otherwise he has no real way of reading it back other than reading to end of file, colllecting the bytes in a collection of `Byte`, and then turning that collection into a `byte[]`. Very laborious. A single `readObject()` would be miles better.

Comment: Not really, he can safely use ObjectOutputStream#write(byte[]) and then ObjectInputStream#readByte() in order to get one byte value, but I agree with your point - leaving this to author of the code.

Comment: The point of reading just one byte escapes me. Seems like yet another protocol error to me.